# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\log \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right) =\log(1+N)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have to prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\log \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right) =\log(1+N)$$
How can i prove it?
I know that
$\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^k}{k}$
For $|x|<1$ and $x=1$
But im not sure if it needs to be used at all.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: *Hint:* $\log (1 + \frac 1n) = \log \frac{n+1}{n}$ and 

Comment: $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$ using this apply induction!!!

Comment: Don't think too far. Try $N=2$, $N=3$, and $N=4$ and you will see some pattern.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1089748/42969

Comment: Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: Telescopic…$\mbox{}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log \left ( 1+\dfrac{1}{n} \right) 
&= \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log \left ( \dfrac{n+1}{n} \right) \\
&= \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left ( \log (n+1) - \log(n) \right) \\
&= \left (\log(2) - \log(1) \right) + \left (\log(3) - \log(2)\right) + \ldots + \left ( \log(N+1) - \log(N) \right ) \\
&= \log(N+1) - \log(1) \\
&= \log(N+1)
\end{align*}